# Telerik controls : Combobox and RadDatePicker not inline on IE 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, telerik, rad-controls

My code design :

```
 Keyword:<telerik:RadTextBox ID="rtbSearch" runat="server" Skin="Web20" Width="150px" EmptyMessage="Enter customer name..."></telerik:RadTextBox>
            <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbProvince" Skin="Web20" runat="server"></telerik:RadComboBox>
            Start <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpStartDay" Skin="Web20" runat="server">
                  </telerik:RadDatePicker>
            End <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpEndDay" Skin="Web20" runat="server">
                </telerik:RadDatePicker>
            <telerik:RadButton ID="rbSearch" Text="Search" runat="server" Skin="Web20"></telerik:RadButton>
```

[image]

how to fix it, please help me, thanks.

p/s: it display perfect on other browsers

chrome :

[image]

Comment: What do you need help with, specifically?

Comment: i want all of controls display in one line

Comment: This is radcontrols of Telerik, so i don't know how to post it on JSFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after search and ask, i know the reason. I used Q3 2012 of controls telerik, so it not support for IE 11